# displaying datepicker on actionsheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was doing [this tutorial](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=301851) that would display a `DatePicker` on an `ActionSheet`. It has the format of `year-mm-dd hh-mm-AM`, but i only need to display the `Year-mm-dd`. How should i do this ?

Comment: Did you even try anything before posting?

Answer (score 1):

Use `YYYY-MM-dd` as a format specifier.  See the [tr35-10](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) standard for more information.

To prompt the user for a date without a time, set the `datePickerMode` property of the UIDatePicker to `UIDatePickerModeDate`.